# Change of message appearing after removal of @lerts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, notifications, alerts

See my original question here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99104/posting-comments-where-whoever-is-removed-and-prevents-posting-due-to-short-comm

**I understand why @alerts are being removed.**

My question is related to the inconsistency between the 'characters remaining' count while typing and the removal of the @alert pushing the count under the limit.

It was very confusing for me, as i'd type away, see that the comment had enough characters, then be presented with the message.

I think a lot of new (and existing?) users would find this confusing.

**In this case (where removal of an @Alert is directly responsible for making a comment under the char limit) should a more appropriate message should be displayed?**

(I'm not questioning the decision to remove @alerts that would be sent anyway.)

Comment: Are people still using comments as chat?

Comment: I don't understand how this is different than the original question you asked....

Comment: Imagine someone types `@postername, great answer!` - is that using comments as chat? I don't think so. It will produce a confusing user experience for the person typing it (who will probably edit it to `thanks, great answer!` which really hasn't made the universe better.

Comment: @Cody, it is pretty much the same question, but i was hoping for responses relating specifically to the message that comes up in this case, rather than a debate re. Alerts and their usage.